# Can't access values for Axios calls in map loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

I have a javascript object with the IDs corresponding to a set of galleries.
I loop through it using map.
On each loop, I make an axios call to get the gallery for the current id.

In the end, I need to have an array with all the galleries content.

The problem is I can't access the data after the map loop is done. I see all the data when I console.log(galleries) but not when I do console.log(galleries[0].gallery).

I suspect this has to be with the async calls.
I'm new to react so I'm might be missing something simple.

Extra info: this is a React Native project, with redux thunk.

Help please and thank you.

```
export function FetchGalleries( galleries_ids ) {

    return function (dispatch) {

        let galleries = [];
        galleries_ids.map( (record, index) =>
        {

            axios.get('https://e.dgyd.com.ar/wp-json/wp/v2/media?_embed&parent='+record.id)
              .then(response => {
                galleries.push( response );
              });

        });

        console.log(galleries); // I can see all data
        console.log( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( galleries[0].gallery ))); // returns undefined
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_GALLERIES_SUCCESS, payload: galleries })

      }
}
```

Comment: `I can see all data` - because the console "lies" ... I bet the console.log says the array has  length of ZERO - the problem is, asynchrony ... you're not playing with it correctly ... besides that, why are you using `.map` ... if you don't return anything!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, I read about the tricky console, tried every solution given in that question with no luck :(

Comment: you must've passed over the parts that tell you how to deal with asynchrony ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest solution is to **wait** for ALL the promises to resolve, then deal with the results

```
export function FetchGalleries( galleries_ids ) {

    return function (dispatch) {
        return Promise.all(galleries_ids.map( (record, index) => {
            return axios.get('https://e.dgyd.com.ar/wp-json/wp/v2/media?_embed&parent='+record.id);
        })).then(galleries => {
            dispatch({ type: FETCH_GALLERIES_SUCCESS, payload: galleries });
        });
    }
}
```