# Can't loop through array using map loop with react.js & axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend

I am fetching data from an API, i get all the data in the console.log(this.state.reviews) but i can't access the data after the map loop is done.

The Brand data is accessible, the only problem is with the map loop (the reviews array)

I know it has something with async calls! i have found this [Can't access values for Axios calls in map loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969613/cant-access-values-for-axios-calls-in-map-loop) Does anyone know how to adapt it with the code below ;-)

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        reviews : []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://api.prime.com/businesses/reviews/${this.props.BrandId}`)
    .then((res) => {
        const brand = res.data;
        this.setState({
            // Reviews data
            reviews : brand.reviews.items,
            // Brand data
            logo   : brand.business.logo,
            name   : brand.business.name,
            voters : brand.business.voters,
            url    : brand.business.url
        });
    })
}
    render() {
    console.log(this.state.reviews);
    return (
            <div className="widget-wrapper">

                    <OwlCarousel className="reviews-container"
                        loop
                        nav
                        margin={12}
                        dots={false}
                        items={5}
                        autoplay={true}
                    >
                        {this.state.reviews.map((review) => {
                            <div key={review.id} className="review-item">
                                <a href={this.state.url + '/' + review.slug} target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
                                    <div className="review-heading">{review.subject}</div>
                                    <div className="review-content">{review.message}</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        })}
                    </OwlCarousel>

            </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: You need a `return` in the `.map` arrow function, or change your `.map` arrow function to use a `(`. Because you're using `this.state.reviews.map((review) => {` (with a curly bracket) the return is not implicit like it would be if using a `(`.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I've already tried this but i didn't work, i think it has something with async calls

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody i don't get errors, it's the same thing as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969613/cant-access-values-for-axios-calls-in-map-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out your problem you need to wait for the promise to resolve that why your state is not set for doing this u can use `async await` like

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }
  loadData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    if (res) {
      const posts = res.data;
      this.setState({
        posts: [...posts]
      });
    }
  };
  renderPost = () => {
    return this.state.posts
      ? this.state.posts.map(data => (
          <div style={{ color: "black" }}>
            <h5>{data.title}</h5>
            <p>{data.body}</p>
          </div>
        ))
      : "loading...";
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.posts);
    return <div> {this.renderPost()}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

full app is here check it out : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-edison-ser1j)

Comment: I don't get errors, i just cant loop the array reviews, i can see the data in console.log(this.state.reviews) but i can't show it

Comment: Your code returns the error Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined (constructor(props) {)

Comment: @Elchy check sandbox its working i don't know what you did wrong in your code!

Comment: i think it's because of the babel-plugin-transform-runtime

Comment: Yes, ur code works :), i had to change the version of @babel/plugin-transform-runtime. Thanks